# Find shell script - logs (SUSE Linux, bash, if, find)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, find

## I have a problem with find command in shell script.

My script finds the archives then unpacks some logs from it and tar the results move it level up and remove file that were created in process.

And there is a problem it will do all operation even when script didn't find archive or logs as a result it creating empty tar. with name:

```
date_patern_patern.tar
```

i was trying fix it using if-statement or && and || operators but i can't handle it could you please direct me how to do it ?

I have modified the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf " -----\nSerch date: $1 \n"
printf "Serch patern: $2 \n"
printf "serch patern: $3 \n -----\n\n"

printf "Serch archives:\n"
mkdir /cc/xx/logs/aaa/envelop/tmp

find archives/ -name "$1_*_messages.tar.gz" -exec cp {} tmp \;
    ls -l tmp/$1_*_messages.tar.gz || exit 1
    cd tmp
    tar -xf $1_*_messages.tar.gz --wildcards --no-anchored "*$2_$3*"
    printf "Find envelop:\n"
    ls -l alsb-message/ || exit 1
    mv alsb-message $1_$2_$3
    tar -cvf $1_$2_$3.tar $1_$2_$3
    mv $1_$2_$3.tar ..
    rm *.gz
    rm -R $1_$2_$3
    cd ..
    rm -r tmp
```

there is another problem i want my script to stop when it serch and doesn't find patern in example when schript is serching:

```
./serch_script.sh 20151110 patern2 patern3
```

and it doesn't find either parern2 or patern3 i want it to stop but it do again empyt .tar i tried to do like Prasanna told but it didn't work in this case,

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html In short, you script is deeply troubled in almost every respect, so I don't even need to read your problem description. Fix what you can fix first.

Comment: Please can you make the first paragraph clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace following line

```
ls -l tmp/
```

with following line

```
ls -l tmp/$1_*_messages.tar.gz || exit 1
```

Basically with this code, you are running `exit 1` if there are no files in tmp directory matching your criteria.

Comment: it helped thanks. But there is another problem i want my script to stop when it serch and doesn't find patern in example when schript is serching:
    ./serch_script.sh 20151110 patern2 patern3
and it doesn't find either parern2 or patern3 i want it to stop but it do the empyt tar insted.

Comment: Try changing `ls -l alsb-message/ || exit 1` to `ls -l alsb-message/* || exit 1`.